# Plex Media Server Working on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, configuration, 16.10, plex

Does anyone know how to get Plex Media Server to work with Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you separate solution from the question and post it as answer.

Comment: I don't have privileges to post comments or answers on other posts and I just wanted to help others....Let me try to answer this post and edit my answer as a question....

Comment: Actually, you can make answer, and comment only on your own posts. See below do you notice the `answer your question` button. post the down there as an answer, then update the question to keep only the issue with its its description. See [about]

Comment: Nice you have already got that, could you extend the question with more details of the problem you have faced and reference some links to the instructions you have followed but did work.

Comment: I don't recall all the other posts I have tried including one YouTube Video that crashed my system (It had people editing the fstab file), which I assume caused my system not to boot. If I come across them I will post them on here. The main problem was that none of the other help topics addressed what Version of Ubuntu they were getting to work with PMS and never addressed 16.04 or in my 1st case scenario, 16.10 specifically.

Answer (score 3):

For 16.04 you need to edit this file:

`/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service`

and run this command:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then you can stop and start plex

```
service plexmediaserver stop

service plexmediaserver start
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu 14.04 *Only*

I have tried to follow several posts for setting up a Plex Media Server on Ubnutu 16.04 and up with no luck. It works perfectly on 14.04 so I suggest if you are having difficulties as I did, Just use 14.04 and the setup is very straight forward.

1. The only change that is needed is editing this file:

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/default/plexmediaserver
   ```

   and changing the plex user to you as here:

   ```
    export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_USER=steve
   ```

   The user that PMS should run as, defaults to 'plex'
   note that if you change this you might need to move
   the Application Support directory to not lose your
   media library (match what is in `/etc/passwd`)
2. Changing Groups and restarting Service

   Stop the service:

   ```
    sudo service plexmediaserver stop
   ```

   Then add user steve to Group Plex:

   ```
    sudo addgroup plex steve
   ```

   and finally start back the service:

   ```
    sudo service plexmediaserver start
   ```

I hope this helps someone like me that spent 2 days banging their head on the keyboard! :)

Comment: Is this for 16.04 or 14.04?

Comment: I could only get 14.04 to work..I tried 16.10 and 16.04, and none of the topics I read helped.

Comment: By the way, after I got everything installed and running on 14.04, I once again upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and everything works fine now!